# How do I skip some of the initializers for a two-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, initialization

I have the following definition

```
static readonly String[,] allItems = {
    { "Alpha", null },
    { "Beta", "Magic" },
    { "Gamma", null },
    // more items follow
}
```

In the first column all items must be initialized to some string literals. In the second column only a small fraction of items must be initialized to string literals and all others are null.

I now need to add the third column and it will mostly contain `null`s and I'd be happy to omit typing all of them.

Is there a way to somehow omit those `null` values?

Comment: Ctrl+H and replace "}," onto ", null }," ? :)

Comment: It sounds you're using a wrong data structure. What that `string[,]` holds? Why not create a class which holds the data for you?

Comment: Not if you use an initializer like that.

You can initialize it the 'old way' (by using the indices inside a static constructor), but that may not be much of an improvement.
Maybe you need to use a Dictionary or define a class/struct which holds your data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but have you considered using an object instead. You can then give default values and only supply ones that are different.

for example

```
public class YourObject{    
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public string SomethingElse {get;set;}

    public YourObject()
    {
        //provide defaults here
        SomethingElse = "";
    }

}
```

Then to create objects you can create like so

```
static readonly List<YourObject> allItems = new List<YourObject>{
    new YourObject{ Name = "Alpha" },
    new YourObject{ Name = "Beta", Value = "Magic" },
    new YourObject{ Name = "Gamma", SomethingElse = "Hello" }
    // more items follow
}
```

Sriram Sakthivel suggested this whilst i was typing ;)

Comment: `()` is redundant in `YourObject` as well as `List`

Comment: Yeah, I was already typing my version of this as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx for more info.

Comment: If `Name` is _always_ required then consider adding it as constructor parameter.

Comment: @ken2k that is true, i'll leave mine as is as this is demonstrated in Amit's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try out list.
that would allow you to add only required elements. You can add further elements later on

List  allList=new List;
allList.Add()

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and then use a collection:

```
class MyClass
{
   public string Prop1 {get;set;}
   public string Prop2 {get;set;}   
   public MyClass(string prop1, string prop2 = null)
   {
       this.Prop1 = prop1;
       this.Prop2 = prop2   
   }
}
```

Now, you can use a `List<T>`

```
var list = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass("Alpha"),
    new MyClass("Beta" , "Magic"),
    new MyClass("Gamme")    
}
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that by adding it as an optional parameter it is effectively baked into the c# call. this could be bad if it was in an assembly. if the assembly is then updated it would need to be recompiled both in the source and the consuming application. If not default values could be old or even worse if an extra optional value is added, it could throw errors. "Optional parameters are best avoided in public functions if you want to offer binary compatibility between assembly versions" Info and Quote from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/ C# 5.0 in a Nutshell

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about number of columns and you want to define just like table then I recommend you using DataTable. Thus you can define column type and enforce any constraint.  This way you can even use Linq to manipulate values.

Here is the sample code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

//
// Here we add five DataRows.
//
table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
return table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class modelling a jagged two dimensional array that can be initialized using a collection initializer. The class has to implement `IEnumerable` and should have an appropriate `Add` method:

```
class Table<T> : IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> {

  readonly List<T[]> rows = new List<T[]>();

  public void Add(params T[] row) {
    rows.Add(row);
  }

  public IEnumerator<IEnumerable<T>> GetEnumerator() {
    return rows.GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }

}
```

You can then use this class directly by say implementing an indexer (`public T this[Int32 rowIndex, Int32 columnIndex] { get { ... } }`) but a better solution is probably to create a method that converts the table to an array:

```
public T[,] ToArray() {
  var columnCount = rows.Max(row => row.Length);
  var array = new T[rows.Count, columnCount];
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.Count; rowIndex += 1)
    for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex += 1) {
      var row = rows[rowIndex];
      array[rowIndex, columnIndex] = columnIndex < row.Length
        ? row[columnIndex] : default(T);
    }
  return array;
}
```

You can then initialize the two dimensional array using this code:

```
static readonly String[,] allItems = new Table<String> {
  { "Alpha" },
  { "Beta", "Magic" },
  { "Gamma" },
}.ToArray();
```